# preload the selected values of a kendo multiselect that using a server bound data source and templated tags

Tags: initialization, kendo-ui, multi-select

I have a kendo multiselect as follows.

```
$("#tags").kendoMultiSelect({
    change: onChange,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            prefix: "",
            read: {
                url: "/OpsManager/Api/Activity/SearchResourcesTagged",
                data: getSubmitData
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true,
        filter: [],
        schema: { errors: "Errors" }
    },
    itemTemplate: $('#resourceItemTemplate').html(),
    tagTemplate: $('#resourceTagTemplate').html(),
    dataValueField: "k",
    value: [{"k":"[109]","n":"All Open Alerts","icon":"!","all":105}]
});
```

with the following templates:

```
<script id="resourceItemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span data-icon="#:data.icon#" class="#: data.s || '' #">&nbsp;#:data.n #</span>  
    # if (data.d) { #
        <div class="details">#: data.d #</div>
    # } #
    # if (data.details) { #
    <div class="details k-state-disabled">
        # for (var v in data.details) { 
            var t = typeof data.details[v];
            if (t != "object" && t != "function" && v != "uid") { #
        <div class="k-button">#: v #: #: data.details[v] #</div>
        # } } #
    </div>
    # } #      
</script>

<script id="resourceTagTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span data-icon="#:data.icon#" class="tag-content #: data.s || '' #">&nbsp;#:data.n #</span> 
</script>
<select id="tags" multiple="multiple" name="tags"></select>
```

I'm trying to preload a specific selection and I can't seem to get it to work.

selection:

```
[{"k":"[109]","n":"All Open Alerts","icon":"!","all":105}]
```

I've put the initialized value in place according to their documentation and looking the multiselect object up inside the browser I see the passed in object inside _initialValues but I don't see anything inside _dataItems or in the tag list on the ui.

Any clues how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OnaBai,

The problem is a difference in expected content of the datasources.  The datasource originally loaded is not looking for "[109]" but rather "some string query" and then provides a specific list around that search.  Thus I need to initialize a fake datasource for the control and then immediately switch out the data source for the dynamic one.

```
$("#tags").kendoMultiSelect({
    change: onChange,
    dataSource: {
        transport : {
            read: function (op) {
                op.success([{"k":"[109]","n":"All Open Alerts","icon":"!","all":105}]);
            }
        }
    },
    itemTemplate: $('#resourceItemTemplate').html(),
    tagTemplate: $('#resourceTagTemplate').html(),
    dataValueField: "k",
    value: ["[109]"]
});
$("#tags").data("kendoMultiSelect").setDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "OpsManager/Api/Activity/SearchResourcesTagged",
            data: getSubmitData
            }
        },
    serverFiltering: true,
    filter: [],
    schema: { errors: "Errors" }
});
```

after that it works exactly like expected.

Comment: There is something that I do not understand. What is `getSubmitedData`? What is the format of the JSON returned by your service `SearchResourcesTagged`? Why do you need to change the `DataSource`?

Comment: getSubmittedData formats the data source call to have a query value.  The service returns a json format like the this

`[{"k":"[109]","n":"All Open Alerts","icon":"!","all":105}]`

Comment: Still don't get why you cannot directly use the DataSource and need to do it in two steps but I'm glad that you have been able to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Define `value` in `multiselect` and not in `dataSource`.
2. Set `value` to an `array` with the list of key values that you want to initially load (in your case just `"[109]"`).

Something like:

```
$("#tags").kendoMultiSelect({
    change: onChange,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            prefix: "",
            read: {
                url: "/OpsManager/Api/Activity/SearchResourcesTagged",
                data: getSubmitData
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true,
        filter: [],
        schema: { errors: "Errors" }
    },
    itemTemplate: $('#resourceItemTemplate').html(),
    tagTemplate: $('#resourceTagTemplate').html(),
    dataValueField: "k",
    value: ["[109]"]
});
```

Example in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yBCtc/)

Comment: sorry, my op was incorrect on the placement of value, it was in the correct place.  Updating my op now.

Comment: Does it mean that my proposed solution does not work? Please check the link to the example (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yBCtc/)

Comment: I've updated my op,  tried your direction out and that doesn't work.  doesn't matter what I put in the "value" it will fill in the _initicalValues object with what I pass in but never translate that to tags.

Comment: actually, I think I figured it out.  I'll have to preload my data source like you are doing in your fiddle, THEN after initial load, update data source to be the dynamic one.  Think that will work?

Comment: No, I don't think that you need it. Check jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yBCtc/1 you will see that even with a delayed answer it sets correctly the values

Comment: The proposed solution won't work. Where would the multiselect get the rest of the data for the template when you specify only id? It won't read it from the server for sure. I'm struggling with that a lot now. The solution danatcofo proposes (putting the whole models to the value) works for me - using Html Kendo helper in Razor view. But it stops working when the modelstate is invalid, then instead of whole models only ids are serialized so nothing is selected in multiselect.